# Unfamiliar C systax - declaring variables after a struct

Tags: c, struct

```
 #include "stdio.h"
  void main( )
  {
   struct {
    char initial;
    int age;
    int grade;
   } kids[12], *point, extra;
```

I am following the tutorial from here http://www.gatesit.org/gitdownloads/C&DS.pdf page 813-22 and I don't quite understand what  kids[12], *point, extra; means. From what I know you can initialize variables of the struct after the definition of it like that but why is there an array size 12, a pointer and extra?

Here is the code following it.

```
 int index;
 for (index = 0; index < 12; index++)
{
  point = kids + index;
  point->initial = 'A' + index;
  point->age = 16;
  point->grade = 84;
 }

 kids[3].age = kids[5].age = 17;
 kids[2].grade = kids[6].grade = 92;
 kids[4].grade = 57;

 for (index = 0; index < 12; index++)
 {
  point = kids + index;
  printf("%c is %d years old and got a grade of %d\n",
  (*point).initial, kids[index].age, point->grade);
 }

 extra = kids[2]; /* Structure assignment */
 extra = *point; /* Structure assignment */

 }
```

Comment: Unfamiliar C semantics: main() should return int. either `int main(void){...}` or `int main(int c, char **v){...}`

Comment: @wildplasser I don't understand what you mean, all the tutorials do what I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct mystruct {
    char initial;
    int age;
    int grade;
} kids[12], *point, extra;
```

is equivalent to:

```
struct mystruct {
    char initial;
    int age;
    int grade;
};
struct mystruct kids[12];
struct mystruct *point;
struct mystruct extra;
```

In your particular case, your struct doesn't have a tag name, so you actually can't create any instances of it afterwards - this is the only way you could do it, since it's unnamed.

Since here the struct is being defined inside a function, and its definition will only be available in that function, then it's likely you won't need to define any more instances of it, so there's no disadvantage of not having a name. On the other hand, other than having one less name in the tag namespace (and therefore avoiding the possibility of hiding a tag name at file scope), there's no particular advantage to it, either.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct {
    char initial;
    int age;
    int grade;
} kids[12], *point, extra;
```

This struct is unnamed.

This creates an array of 12 of this struct, named `kids`, a pointer to this type of struct named `point`, and another one of these structs named `extra`.

For a one-off structure, used only in a few limited places, this is acceptable. In a larger usage case, I would consider this kind of "sloppy", and would prefer to see something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char initial;
    int age;
    int grade;
} student_t;

int main() {
    student_t kids[12];     // 12 students in the class
    student_t* pStudent;    // A pointer to a student_t
    student_t extra;        // The new kid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a 12 element array of the `struct`, a variable that is of the `struct` type, and a pointer to the `struct`. Then the code shows the different ways in which those types of variables can be used to access the inner pieces of the `struct`, and how the items can be assigned among each other.

Answer (score 1):

This basically defined an array of 12 elements of the defined struct `kids[12]`, another variable that is a single pointer to the defined struct `*point` and finally a single instance of the struct `extra`.

Since the struct doesn't have a name, I suppose you'd have to define all of them at once next to the struct definition.

Equivalently, it could've been something like this:

```
struct kid {
    char initial;
    int age;
    int grade;
   };

struct kid kids[12];
struct kid *pointer;
struct kid extra;
```